# Что такое постоянный размер раздела и как его выбрать? Rufus

Tags: linux, elementary-os

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Хочу второй ОС установить elementaryOS. Что такое постоянный размер раздела и как его выбрать?
Спасибо

Comment: что означают используемые в поделке термины — спрашивайте у авторов поделки.

Comment: Запустите в английской локали — будет намного понятнее.

Comment: Скорее всего речь идёт про это: https://compizomania.blogspot.com/2019/10/live-usb-persistent-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 1):

Это размер постоянного хранилища. Тот размер, что будет доступен операционной системе, если вы запускаете её с флешки (Именно запускаете, а не устанавливаете). 
Если вы устанавливаете на жесткий диск, этот пункт для вас значения не имеет.